# How to duplicate and sync tables based on ID column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to duplicate a table in Excel onto a different worksheet, add columns to the new table, and keep the rows synced.

(p.s I'm not sure how to add images of the Excel sheet in here?)

For example, I have a table (Table1):

```
ID    Data  
A     1  
B     2  
C     3  
D     4
```

I'd like to duplicate it in another sheet (Table2) and add a column that's only in the new table:

```
ID    Data   Data2  
A     1      a  
B     2      b  
C     3      c  
D     4      d
```

And I'd keep the rows synced, so that if I add, delete or amend a row in the original table (Table1), the new table (Table2) remains consistent **including the added column that only exists in the new table**.

For example, if I delete the row with ID "B" in the original table, I'd like this to happen in the new table:

```
ID    Data   Data2  
A     1      a  
C     3      c  
D     4      d
```

I've been able to duplicate the table via a connection or query, but the added column in the new table doesn't stay in sync. For example, at the moment if I delete the row with ID "B" in the original table, this happens in the new table:

```
ID    Data   Data2  
A     1      a  
C     3      b  
D     4      c
```

The columns that are in the original table update correctly, while the new column seems to be ignored.

I need to use Excel and if possible without VBA, but if VBA is the only way this will work then I'll need to use it.

I'm pretty desperate so any tips in the right direction would be gratefully received!!

Comment: You can achieve most of this with just using `VLOOKUP`, but you need a permanent reference somewhere so that you can populate your `Data2` column - otherwise, when you add/remove a row, how is that data supposed to return?

Comment: I've been playing with VLOOKUPs but can't get them to work. My issue is that I need to have a single master table with the IDs, which means I can't think of a solution that'd have a permanent reference between the IDs and the Data2 column (that doesn't just reproduce the problem I have above). I'm fairly tired, does that make sense?

Comment: Why do this though?  You can much easier use one sheet and toggle the extra column visibility.  Two sheets adds a bunch of unnecessary complexity

Comment: @TimWilliams Because with 1 sheet, the sheet itself can be "unnecessarily complex" in the sense that User 1 may want to only see Data, while User 2 maybe only want to see Data 2. When there are dozens of columns, it gets to be a huge mess very quickly (hence I'm also trying to do the same thing as the OP, but also can't get it to work ha!)

Comment: A single table with buttons to configure "views" (hide/show columns) still seems easier to manage.